# Padding makes the element bigger instead of clear the space around the element

Tags: css

So here's my code

```
    <style>
    body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

    .mouse{
    background-color: rgb(128,64,0);
    border-radius:100px;
    height:100%;
    width:10%;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    .left_ear{
    background-color: red;
    border-radius:100px;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    padding:100%;

    }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
        <div class="mouse" id="mouse1">
            <div class="left_ear"></div>
            <div class="right_ear"></div>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="mouse" id="mouse2">
            <div class="left_ear"></div>
            <div class="right_ear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mouse" id="mouse3">
            <div class="left_ear"></div>
            <div class="right_ear"></div>
        </div>-->   
</body>

</html>
```

This is what I get with:
[Padding: 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSM2F.jpg)

[Padding: 30%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk4px.jpg)

So how does padding work? I mean I know the basics that it'll increase the surrounding area of the element, but never increases the element's size.

Comment: maybe you're looking for `box-sizing: border-box;`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: perhaps try `margin` and not `padding`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you got elements like this:

```css
.parent{
  padding:20px;
  background:blue;
  display:inline-block;
}
.parent div{
  padding:20px;
  height:80px;
  width:80px;
}
.child1{
  background:green;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.child2{
  background:purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div><br>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the first child is smaller than the second one, although they got the exact **same size and padding**.
On the first child I used the property `box-sizing:border-box`. What this does, it *includes* the padding in the elements width/height.
If you don't do that, the padding gets *added* to the elements width.
In your example, you got `box-sizing:border-box` on the parent element. So if you added margin to that element, it'd stay the same size (except you set more padding than the element is big). On your children, you haven't got this property, so their size gets increased, when using padding.